# Showing a column in relationship issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app to show a column from another table but is not working

Here my tables

```
|policies|
 |id|  |num_policy|

|insurances|
 |id|  |id_policy| |net_insurance| 

|insurance_financing|       
  |id| |id_ensurance| |number|
```

This is my controller

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print
      @policies= Policy.find(:all)
    end
end
```

This is my model

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurances
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
  has_many :insurance_financing_details
end

class InsuranceFinancingDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insurance
end
```

This is my view

```
<% @policies.each do |p| %>

     <%= p.num_policy   %>

     <%  p.insurances.insurance_financing_details.each do |insurance| %>
       <%= insurance.number %>
     <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This is my error

```
undefined method `insurance_financing_details'
```

This i also tried  <%  p.insurance_financing_details.each do |insurance| %>

```
undefined method `insurance_financing_details'
```

Please somebody can help me with this problem

I will really appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p.insurances will give you an array. Following should work. But be aware that there is going to be a performace hit when you have large number of policies and insurances

```
<% @policies.each do |p| %>
     <%= p.num_policy   %>

     <%  p.insurances.each do |insurance| %>
       <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.each do |detail| %>
         <%= detail.number %>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>

<% end %>
```